# How to filter the search results collection using the category id?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I had added a category dropdown in `form.mini.phtml` file and submitted the search form. I tried modifying the collection of the `list.phtml` file which is in `Magento_Catalog` module but hard luck. Kindly advice how to filter the search result product collection using the category id.

Comment: hae you tried funtion `addFeildToFilter('feild',$value)` of magento category Collection

Comment: I have tried it in list.phtml for $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (Magento 2.3)

```
addCategoryFilter($category)
```

on collection

Please refer below path

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Advanced/Collection.php
```